# For loop doesn't loop at all (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, dom, for-loop

I am beginner in JavaScript and I can't figure out the following problem: I am trying to create a simple JavaScript game which should allow user to enter names of the players.

I tried to solve this with 'for' loop which would repeat let's say 5-times (according to users previous choice). However, when I try to loop the following code which should allow user to type the names of players, it always starts at nr. 4 and doesn't loop anymore but ends instead. Why is that so? How could I improve my code so that it worked?

```
for (var i=0; i<5;i++){
    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = '<form name=players_name><p>Name of the player '+
                                                   i+
                                                   '</p><input type="text" name="player_name"></br><input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="somefunction()"></form>';
}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: No it doesn't. It gets overwritten, five times, the final time saying `4`. Adding a simple `alert` to debug the problem would have shown this and narrowed the issue down.

Comment: I put together a more [sophisticated example](http://jsfiddle.net/9UgrA/) that demonstrates a process of appending ad hoc a list of players, as well as some other techniques like basic templating, recursion on a list (`playertpml`, be careful with that), et al. The use of the `.innerHTML +=` I have in the `addplayers` functions is alright; it's doing that form in a loop that it becomes problematic. I figured I'd clarify that.

Comment: @JaredFarrish-Thank you, that is perfect!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `+=` operator to append the HTML on each iteration:

```
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML += "...";
```

But doing this degrades performance. Rather, use an array to collect the strings and put them into the element at the end of the loop:

```
for (var i = 0, html = []; i < 5; i++) {
    html.push( '..' );
}

document.getElementById('content') = html.join();
```

Comment: Keep in mind...! `+=` in combo with `.innerHTML` can be hazardous to your response time. It's slow. Slooow.

Comment: push all the generated HTML into an array, join them when the loop is over would better, huh?

Comment: David: Thanks, it works. But now, the 5 forms are on the screen at the same time - is there any simple way to show them one after another?

Comment: @FilipCapanda In the string, put a line break `<br>` and the very end. Put as many as you like actually to separate them. Or did you mean you wanted only one to be visible at a time?

Comment: I wanted only one to be visible at a time (sorry for bad English)

Comment: @FilipCapanda That's a bit more complicated since we're working with strings. Actually it's very complicated for quite a few reasons..

Comment: David: Ok, thanks anyway.

Comment: @FilipCapanda - "simple way" leads you down the wormhole. Thyre be tygers there. Understand, then implement.

Comment: David: Sorry, Iam newbie here:-)...hope I did it right.

Comment: As a clarification, `innerHTML +=` is only really a problem when performing that *over a loop* like what was demonstrated. It's actually pretty fast compared to other techniques in single-off situations, but not like that with a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `alert()` or `console.log()` to see if it's actually your loop, or, if it's your code within the loop's body.

```
for (var i=0; i<5;i++){
alert(i);
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = '<form name=players_name><p>Name of the player '+i+'</p><input type="text" name="player_name"></br><input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="somefunction()"></form>';
}
```

This will show you a message box with your variable `i`'s value with each iteration.

You can also use

```
console.log(i);
```

with your browser's debug console (be warned, this has some compatibility issues with IE < 8)

Answer (score 0):

<sub>[image]</sub>

```
var content = "";                                          //create "content"
for (var i=0; i<5;i++){
    content += '...'+i+'...'+"<br>";                       //Add your HTML inside
}                                                          //¯¯¯
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = content;    //Put it into DOM
```

So that the innerHTML won't be over written every single time.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a mistake. You overwrite 4 times the content of the HTML element with id "content". So there is the answer, why did you see just the fourth form.

Here is the fixed code:

```
// Make a variable what will contain the forms
var content_output = "";

for (var i=0; i<5;i++){
     content_output += '<form name=players_name><p>Name of the player ' + i + '</p><input type="text" name="player_name"></br><input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="somefunction()"></form>';
}

// Add the content_output variable's content to the HTML element width 'content' id
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = content_output;
```